# Can you stream Audio from a URL in a discord.js resource

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I play audio from a url with discord.js v13.

I used this code and it didn't work.

```
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: channel_id.id,
        guildId: guild_id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });

    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    const resource = createAudioResource('http://radioplayer.kissfmuk.com/live/')
    player.play(resource)

    connection.subscribe(player)
```

I have activated all Intents, the bot shows a green circle but no audio is playing.
Do you have an Idea how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple, I just need to subscribe to the connection before I play the resource!

```
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: channel_id.id,
        guildId: guild_id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });


    const resource = 
    createAudioResource('https://streams.ilovemusic.de/iloveradio8.mp3', {
        inlineVolume: true
    })

    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    connection.subscribe(player)
    player.play(resource)
```

Answer (score 1):

A link of which you are trying to make a resource of, has to return an audio file.
Live audio broadcasts will not work with your current code.
If the url gives you E.g. an .mp3 file, the code should work.

Example Function:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] });

const config =  require('./config/config.json');

const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, NoSubscriberBehavior, createAudioResource, AudioPlayerStatus, VoiceConnectionStatus, entersState } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { join } = require('path');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(config.onlineMessage);
    const channels = client.guilds.cache.find(f => f.name==="<Server Name>").channels;
    JoinChannel(channels.cache.find(r => r.name === "<Channel Name>"), './background.mp3', 0.025);  
});

client.login(config.token);

function JoinChannel(channel, track, volume) {
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: channel.id,
        guildId: channel.guildId,
        adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    resource = createAudioResource(join(__dirname, track), { inlineVolume: true });
resource.volume.setVolume(volume);
    connection.subscribe(player); 
    connection.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, () => {console.log("ready"); player.play(resource);})
    connection.on(VoiceConnectionStatus.Disconnected, async (oldState, newState) => {
        try {
            console.log("Disconnected.")
            await Promise.race([
                entersState(connection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Signalling, 5_000),
                entersState(connection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Connecting, 5_000),
            ]);
        } catch (error) {
            connection.destroy();
        }
    });
    player.on('error', error => {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.message} with resource ${error.resource.metadata.title}`);
        player.play(getNextResource());
    });
    player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Playing, () => {
        console.log('The audio player has started playing!');
    }); 
    player.on('idle', () => {
        connection.destroy();
    })
}
```

Comment: Is an Link possible wich ends with .mp3?
Like: https://streams.ilovemusic.de/iloveradio2.mp3

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Would you update your answer to include the mp3 info? It's very helpful.

Comment: @Éndoxos Can you give me a code example I just wont work